# ios add status window over current view

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm looking to present a window over the entire app (regardless of what view controller is in front/active). Similar to what Songza does (image below). Can I do something like this from within my AppDelegate? If not, where? Also, what is the best way to do something like this (not push a new view but some sort of overlay over the current state of the app?

[image]

Comment: If you email Songza and ask them to forward to the developers. A lot of times, these companies are really helpful. I've done the same with Wunderlist. They gave me all the code I was interested in.

Comment: What I've done before is just brought a new semi-transparent view to the front but it doesn't cover up any nav bars, toolbars, or tab bars. To do something to this full extent may require messing with the UIWindow object itself though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have many options, the easiest solution would be to use [`presentViewController:animated:completion:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/presentViewController%3aanimated%3acompletion%3a).

Alternatively, you could create a container view that holds the rest of your views and includes a function to display your window view, in your function, just make the window view visible and call `[containerView bringToSubviewFront:windowView];`

Another option would be to traverse the windows in your app delegate and add your view to the proper window (SVProgressHUD does this):

```
NSEnumerator *frontToBackWindows = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication]windows]reverseObjectEnumerator];

for (UIWindow *window in frontToBackWindows)
   if (window.windowLevel == UIWindowLevelNormal)
   {
         [window addSubview:self.overlayView];
         break;
    }
```